# How to solve a system of transcendental functions?

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

Having difficulty solving the following instructions:

*Solve the system of simultaneous transcendental equations (e^x+ ln(y) = 2 ; sin(x) + cos(y) = 1). Hint: Look for a solution pair (x,y) that meets both conditions.*

1. How do I get this to give me a value for both x and y?
2. What do the error messages mean?

Here is my input and output:

```
In[32]:= eq1 = Exp[x] + Ln[y] -2
eq2 = Sin[x] + Cos[y] - 1
system = Solve[eq1 == 0 & eq2 == 0, {x, y}]

Out[32]= -2 + E^x + Ln[y]

Out[33]= -1 + Cos[y] + Sin[x]

During evaluation of In[32]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

During evaluation of In[32]:= Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.

Out[34]= {{y -> -ArcCos[1 - Sin[x]]}, {y -> ArcCos[1 - Sin[x]]}}
```

Comment: This is that the solution are computed using inverse functions. From the documentation (Solve::ifun): "Inverse functions normally give one branch of a general inverse, so equations that are solved in terms of inverse functions may omit solutions associated with other branches."

Comment: @mgamer is it possible to force it to give me a solution in x?

Comment: Hint: Look up `Ln` in the help system here https://reference.wolfram.com/language/?source=nav and then look up `Log` in the help system. You can also evaluate `Ln[1]` and `Log[1]` and see what you get

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `&`

Comment: Right, others were faster ;-) There are syntactic issues in your code, analytical solution is unlikely, you can use `FindRoot`: `Plot[{Exp[2 - Exp[x]], ArcCos[1 - Sin[x]]}, {x, 0, 4}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, 
   Point[{x, y} /. 
     FindRoot[{Exp[x] + Log[y] == 2, Sin[x] + Cos[y] == 1}, {x, 
       0.8}, {y, 0.8}]]}
 ]`

Comment: "`Ln`"?  Surprised you didn't get more diagnostic output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The system under consideration can be solved numerically. First, the plot

```
eq1 = Exp[x] + Log[y] - 2;eq2 = Sin[x] + Cos[y] - 1;
ContourPlot[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

[image]

suggests the location of the only real solution within these bounds. Second,

```
FindRoot[eq1 == 0 && eq2 == 0, {{x, 1}, {y, 1}}]
*{x -> 0.624295, y -> 1.14233} *
```

Similar questions were asked and answered a lot.

Comment: there are more solutions though: try `ContourPlot[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0}, {x, -2Pi, 2Pi}, {y, 0, 4*Pi}]`

Comment: @chris: Thank you for your valuable comment. There  is likely an infinite set of the solutions up tp ContourPlot[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0}, {x, -16*\[Pi], 6*\[Pi]}, {y, 0, 
  4 \[Pi]}].

Answer (score 4):

```
eq1 = Exp[x] + Log[y] - 2; eq2 = Sin[x] + Cos[y] - 1;
```

By specifying a region of interest (i.e., bounds on `x` and `y`), you can use either [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) or [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html). This eliminates the need for initial estimates.

```
pts = NSolve[eq1 == 0 && eq2 == 0 && -2 Pi < x < 2 Pi && 0 < y < 3 Pi, 
   {x, y}, WorkingPrecision -> 12]

(* {{x -> -5.72429888179, y -> 7.36496544358}, 
    {x -> -3.52187172728, y -> 7.17394645329}, 
    {x -> 0.624294646094, y -> 1.14233150365}, 
    {x -> 3.14159265359, y -> 6.58739712575*10^-10}} *)
```

Verifying the solutions

```
eq1 == 0 && eq2 == 0 /. pts

(* {True, True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: +1. However, ContourPlot[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0}, {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, {y, 0, 3*Pi}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, WorkingPrecision -> 12] shows only three solutions and FindRoot[eq1 == 0 && eq2 == 0, {{x, 3}, {y, 0.1}}] performs $$\{x\to 3.14159\, +\text{1.9843579483064874$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-23} i,y\to \text{6.587397125792588$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-10}-\text{2.7353757755297136$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-20} i\} $$

Comment: @user64494 - the plot has difficulties because the curve is essentially horizontal. Increasing the `PlotPoints` even more and increasing `MaxRecursion` will get progressively closer to displaying a fourth solution, but the plot slows down to a dead stop. I believe that this is essentially a limiting case.

Comment: @user64494 - `FindRoot[eq1 == 0 && eq2 == 0, {{x, 3}, {y, 1/100}}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> #] & /@ Range[20, 50, 10]` suggests that by increasing the `WorkingPrecision` the imaginary parts can be made arbitrarily small.

Comment: Blowing up ContourPlot[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0}, {x, 3, 3.5}, {y, 0, 0.05}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, WorkingPrecision -> 12], I see the fourth root.

Comment: There are more solutions, e. g. `x->-16.2923,y->7.38906`. Seems to be infinitely many, actually

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე: If $x \to -\infty$, then $e^x\to 0$. Therefore, solutions of the system under consideration are close to the solutions of Log[y] - 2==0&&Sin[x] + Cos[y] - 1==0.

Comment: @user64494 Yes, since $y=e^{2-e^x}$ is near zero for $x\gg0$ and near $e^2$ for $x\ll0$, there is a solution near each $x=k\pi$, $\arcsin(1-\cos(e^2))-2k\pi$ and $-\arcsin(1-\cos(e^2))-(2k-1)\pi$ for all $k>0$

Comment: For example, `x->3.141592653589793,y->6.58739712575059*10^-10`